# How can I convert Sqlalchemy table object to Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to convert retrieved SqlAlchemy table object into Pandas DataFrame or do I need to write a particular function for that aim ?

Comment: Have you considered using [pandas.read_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html#pandas.read_sql)?

Comment: Yes but SqlAlchemy has other use cases in my project as well.

Comment: pandas.read_sql can use an SqlAlchemy engine.

Comment: For when you want to use another selectable than just the table (including working with the orm), take a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29528804/1273938

Answer (score 16):

This might not be the most efficient way, but it has worked for me to reflect a database table using `automap_base` and then convert it to a Pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

connection_string = "your:db:connection:string:here"
engine = create_engine(connection_string, echo=False)
session = Session(engine)

# sqlalchemy: Reflect the tables
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

# Mapped classes are now created with names by default matching that of the table name.
Table_Name = Base.classes.table_name

# Example query with filtering
query = session.query(Table_Name).filter(Table_Name.language != 'english')

# Convert to DataFrame
df = pd.read_sql(query.statement, engine)
df.head()
```

Comment: I benchmarked this and the above (more upvoted) answer. This answer is roughly twice as fast, in addition to being simpler. Nice work. Also, thank you.

Comment: Very pythonic and easily extensible. Thank you.

Comment: From SQLAlchemy 1.4, `reflect` parameter is deprecated and reflection is enabled when `autoload_with` is passed (this is the case here with `engine` parameter)

Answer (score 6):

I think I've tried this before.  It's hacky, but for whole-table ORM query results, this should work:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = [c.name for c in SQLA_Table.__table__.columns]
pk = [c.name for c in SQLA_Table.__table__.primary_key]
tuplefied_list = [(getattr(item, col) for col in cols) for item in result_list]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tuplefied_list, index=pk, columns=cols)
```

Partial query results (NamedTuples) will also work, but you have to construct the DataFrame `columns` and `index` to match your query.

Comment: just use `pandas.read_sql` with an SQLAlchemy engine. it's dead simple.

Comment: How do you use `pandas.read_sql` on an ORM query, like: `session.query(MyORMTable).limit(100).all()` ?

Comment: `pandas.read_sql_table('MyTable', MySQLEngine)` see here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0140-sql

Comment: Very cool.  It looks like it doesn't convert existing query results, though (or work with the ORM), which is how I was interpreting the original question.

Comment: What is `result_list` here? I get an error when trying to run this. I also have existing query results that I want to convert to a pandas data frame (as opposed to just loading up a straight table)

Comment: In Python 3, you'll need to invoke `tuple` explicitly: `tuplefied_list = [tuple(getattr(item, col) for col in cols) for item in result_list]`. Otherwise `pd.DataFrame.from_records` does not parse the generator expressions as intended.

Comment: This answer and the comments are symptomatic of terrible database/ORM modeling. Please see @Halee's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas database functions such as `read_sql_query` accept SQLAlchemy connection objects (so-called SQLAlchemy *connectables*, see `pandas` [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) and `sqlalchemy` [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html)). Here's one example of using such object called `my_connection`:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

# create SQLAlchemy Engine object instance 
my_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f"{dialect}+{driver}://{login}:{password}@{host}/{db_name}")

# connect to the database using the newly created Engine instance
my_connection = my_engine.connect()

# run SQL query
my_df = pd.read_sql_query(sql=my_sql_query, con=my_connection)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a ***simpler*** way:

```py
# Step1: import
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Step2: create_engine
connection_string = "sqlite:////absolute/path/to/database.db"
engine = create_engine(connection_string)

# Step3: select table
print (engine.table_names())

# Step4: read table
table_df = pd.read_sql_table('table_name', engine)
table_df.head()
```

For other types of `connection_string`, [SQLAlchemy 1.4 Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html).

Comment: AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'table_names'