# SQLAlchemy ORM conversion to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Is there a solution converting a SQLAlchemy `<Query object>` to a pandas DataFrame?

Pandas has the capability to use `pandas.read_sql` but this requires use of raw SQL. I have two reasons for wanting to avoid it:

1. I already have everything using the ORM (a good reason in and of itself) and
2. I'm using python lists as part of the query, e.g.:

> `db.session.query(Item).filter(Item.symbol.in_(add_symbols)` where `Item` is my model class and `add_symbols` is a list). This is the equivalent of SQL `SELECT ... from ... WHERE ... IN`.

Is anything possible?

Answer (score 265, accepted):

Below should work in most cases:

```
df = pd.read_sql(query.statement, query.session.bind)
```

See [`pandas.read_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) documentation for more information on the parameters.

Comment: @van +1 but could do with a little bit more detail. e.g. I did `df = pd.read_sql(query, query.bind)` when `query` is a `sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select`. Otherwise, I got `'Select' object has no attribute 'session'`.

Comment: In order to to copy-paste, I added link to the documentation directly in the answer, which covers your question: you should provide the `con` parameter, which can be the `engine` or `connection string`

Comment: @van Would it be better to use query.session.connection() here? Otherwise the query doesn't take into account unpersisted changes in the session...

Comment: @dataflow: I think you are right, but i have never tested the assumption.

Comment: @van - this throws 'TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, DefaultMeta found'; been tearing my hair out all day trying to figure out what's wrong. Only thing I can figure is that it might have something to do with trying to extract a connection from a scoped_session....

Comment: Still works for me with the newest version of sqlalchemy and also using scoped sessions. Could you start a chat on the topic and provide more context.

Comment: @dmvianna Having been spoiled by ruby/rails/ActiveRecord, I feel this is normal

Comment: @van I can confirm that using `query.session.bind` does not include upersisted changes in the session, but that using `query.session.connection()` does.  The original answer here was not quite complete for my use case without your suggestion.

Comment: Does anybody have problems with duplicated rows with this approach?

Comment: @aprospero, you should get into `pandas.DataFrame` exactly the result of your sqlalchemy `query`. If it contains duplicates, so will the data frame. However, you can remove duplicates either at pandas or by amending the query, for example by adding a [`distinct()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.distinct) to it.

Comment: fun tip: if you set `engine.execution_options(stream_results = True)` and add `pd.read_sql(..., chunksize = ...)`, you can avoid loading all the data into memory

Answer (score 149):

Just to make this more clear for novice pandas programmers, here is a concrete example,

```
pd.read_sql(session.query(Complaint).filter(Complaint.id == 2).statement,session.bind)
```

Here we select a complaint from complaints table (sqlalchemy model is Complaint) with id = 2

Comment: I think this is more clear, when the code is ORM based.

Comment: OMG! I struggled with sqlAlchemy hell a lot. Just a side note here: You can also write read_sql('SELECT * FROM TABLENAME', db.session.bind) . Thanks. The above answer helped me more than the accepted one.

Comment: What does `.statement` do?

Comment: @cardamom it returns the sql query.

Comment: This gives `NotImplementedError` for SQLAlchemy 2.0

Answer (score 32):

For completeness sake: As alternative to the Pandas-function [`read_sql_query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html), you can also use the Pandas-DataFrame-function [`from_records()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) to convert a `structured or record ndarray to DataFrame`.
This comes in handy if you e.g. have already executed the query in SQLAlchemy and have the results already available:

```
import pandas as pd 
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker


SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/my_database'
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, pool_pre_ping=True, echo=False)
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)


class Currency(Base):
    """The `Currency`-table"""
    __tablename__ = "currency"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "data"}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(64), nullable=False)


# Defining the SQLAlchemy-query
currency_query = db.query(Currency).with_entities(Currency.id, Currency.name)

# Getting all the entries via SQLAlchemy
currencies = currency_query.all()

# We provide also the (alternate) column names and set the index here,
# renaming the column `id` to `currency__id`
df_from_records = pd.DataFrame.from_records(currencies
    , index='currency__id'
    , columns=['currency__id', 'name'])
print(df_from_records.head(5))

# Or getting the entries via Pandas instead of SQLAlchemy using the
# aforementioned function `read_sql_query()`. We can set the index-columns here as well
df_from_query = pd.read_sql_query(currency_query.statement, db.bind, index_col='id')
# Renaming the index-column(s) from `id` to `currency__id` needs another statement
df_from_query.index.rename(name='currency__id', inplace=True)
print(df_from_query.head(5))
```

Comment: pd.DataFrame.from_records was especially helpful in my case - many thanks

Answer (score 21):

The selected solution didn't work for me, as I kept getting the error

> AttributeError: 'AnnotatedSelect' object has no attribute 'lower'

I found the following worked:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(query.statement, engine)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to compile a query with parameters and dialect specific arguments, use something like this:

```
c = query.statement.compile(query.session.bind)
df = pandas.read_sql(c.string, query.session.bind, params=c.params)
```

Comment: This would almost work, trying it in 2022 you need to pass a whole compiled query as a first argument do pandas, not just c.string (whole c). pyodbc version: 4.0.32, sa: 1.4.39

Answer (score 5):

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/DB', echo=False)
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

conn = session.bind

class DailyTrendsTable(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'trends'
    __table_args__ = ({"schema": 'mf_analysis'})

    company_code = Column(DOUBLE_PRECISION, primary_key=True)
    rt_bullish_trending = Column(Integer)
    rt_bearish_trending = Column(Integer)
    rt_bullish_non_trending = Column(Integer)
    rt_bearish_non_trending = Column(Integer)
    gen_date = Column(Date, primary_key=True)

df_query = select([DailyTrendsTable])

df_data = pd.read_sql(rt_daily_query, con = conn)
```

Comment: The import of `select` in `df_query = select([DailyTrendsTable])` is missing. `from sqlalchemy import select`

Answer (score 4):

Simple example using the `Result.keys()` method to get the column names.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd

engine = sa.create_engine(...)
with engine.connect() as conn:
   result = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM foo;")
   df = pd.DataFrame(result.all(), columns=result.keys())
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.keys

Answer (score 2):

Using the `2.0 SQLalchemy` syntax (available also in 1.4 with the flag `future=True`) it looks that `pd.read_sql` is not implemented yet and it will raise:

```
NotImplementedError: This method is not implemented for SQLAlchemy 2.0.
```

This is an open issue that won't be solved till pandas 2.0, you can find some information about this [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/44794) and [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44823#issuecomment-993828292).

I didn't find any satisfactory work around, but some people seems to be using two configurations of the engine, one with the flag future False:

```
engine2 = create_engine(URL_string, echo=False, future=False)
```

This solution would be OK if you query strings, but using the ORM, the best I could do is a custom function yet to be optimized, but it works:

```
Conditions = session.query(ExampleTable)
def df_from_sql(query):
    return pd.DataFrame([i.__dict__ for i in query]).drop(columns='_sa_instance_state')
df = df_from_sql(ExampleTable)
```

This solution in any case would be provisional till pd.read_sql has implemented the new syntax.

Comment: pandas has since been updated to be compatible with SQLAlchemy 2.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using the ORM it's as simple as this:

```
pd.DataFrame([r._asdict() for r in query.all()])
```

Good alternative to `pd.read_sql` when you don't want to expose sql and sessions to the business logic code.

Found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52208023/1635525

Answer (score 0):

This answer provides a reproducible example using an SQL Alchemy `select` statement and returning a pandas data frame. It is based on an in memory SQLite database so that anyone can reproduce it without installing a database engine.

```
import pandas
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Column, Text
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
```

Define table metadata and create a table

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
meta = MetaData()
meta.bind = engine
user_table = Table('user', meta,
                   Column("name", Text),
                   Column("full_name", Text))
user_table.create()
```

[Insert](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.insert) some data into the `user` table

```
stmt = user_table.insert().values(name='Bob', full_name='Sponge Bob')
with Session(engine) as session:
    result = session.execute(stmt)
    session.commit()
```

Read the result of a [select](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_select.html#the-select-sql-expression-construct) statement into a pandas data frame

```
# Select data into a pandas data frame
stmt = user_table.select().where(user_table.c.name == 'Bob')
df = pandas.read_sql_query(stmt, engine)
df
Out:
  name   full_name
0  Bob  Sponge Bob
```

Comment: I use that by I receive error: sqlalchemy.exc.ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object:. Could you help me?

Comment: Do you have the latest versions of sqlalchemy and pandas?

Answer (score 0):

if use SQL query

```
def generate_df_from_sqlquery(query):
   from pandas import DataFrame
   query = db.session.execute(query)
   df = DataFrame(query.fetchall())
   if len(df) > 0:
      df.columns = query.keys()
   else:
      columns = query.keys()
      df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
return df

profile_df = generate_df_from_sqlquery(profile_query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to answers using `read_sql` like @van, when my query involved a join, sqlalchemy seemed to be implicitly adding aliased columns from the join tables like id_1, id_2 incase the join tables and primary table both had an id column for example. Using .all() removes these implicit columns before returning results but `read_sql` will include these columns.

Solutions for that case for me was to be explicit on my selects. So I replaced

```
query = session.query(model)
```

with

```
query = session.query(model.col_1, model.col_2)
```

or for select all

```
query = session.query(*model.__table__.columns.values())
```

then

```
df = pd.read_sql(query.statement, query.session.bind)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this if you've already received the data after sqalchemy filtering is presented [here](https://gist.github.com/garaud/bda10fa55df5723e27da)
Followed by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63743668/8668595) answer, use this function:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from sqlalchemy import inspect
import pandas as pd
def query_to_dict(rest):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for obj in rest:
        instance = inspect(obj)
        for key, x in instance.attrs.items():
            result[key].append(x.value)
    return result
# Getting all the entries via SQLAlchemy
currencies = currency_query.all()
df = pd.DataFrame(query_to_dict(rset))
```

Answer (score 0):

for me this worked for me in 2023: First create a engine and session, convert the query-string into a SQLalchemy text

```
from sqlalchemy import text

    engine = create_engine(path, echo=True)

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    # generates suitble text for SQLalchemy
    sql = text(query_string)

    session.execute(sql)

    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql=sql, con=engine.connect())
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import pandas as pd

users = Users.query.all()

df = pd.DataFrame(users)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**