# SQLAlchemy ORM conversion to Pandas DataFrame with Bigquery

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, google-bigquery

Extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525808/sqlalchemy-orm-conversion-to-pandas-dataframe), which describes the process on how to use the `pandas.read_sql` function from an ORM to get the results of a query directly in a pandas DataFrame.

What I would like would be to be able to do the exact same thing while using SQLAlchemy and [pybigquery](https://github.com/mxmzdlv/pybigquery)

First off I define my session this way:

```py
from sqlalchemy import
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

db_uri = "bigquery://myproject/"
engine = create_engine(db_uri)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

From there I can request from my ORM's `Item`

```
session.query(Item).first()
<Item...>
```

If I had to call a classical SQL database through `pandas.read_sql` I'd juste need to do:

```
query = session.query(...)
df = pandas.read_sql(query.statement, session.query.bind)
```

Naively, I tried

```
pandas.read_bgq(query.statement)
```

But that returns `TypeError: Object of type 'Select' is not JSON serializable`

Is there a way to request bigquery directly into a pandas dataframe the same way as for classical SQL database ?

Comment: What happens if you try `pandas.read_sql` with the BigQuery query statement?

Comment: mmh, interesting, that actually seems to work ! Had a previously unrelated error when trying it I guess

Comment: Will miss the progress bar though ;/

Comment: I never could read the BigqQuery data like this way. Thus, I always use the traditional read method of Python Google SDK: `bigquery.Client().query`. I guess this method safer.

Comment: @LoicM, Did you fix the issue? If yes, please finalize the question and add the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @TimSwast's comment:

Using regular query statement with the `pandas.read_sql` actually works ! So this would look like this:

```py
query = session.query(...)
df = pandas.read_sql(query.statement, session.query.bind)
```