# Getting query statement from ORM in Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, orm

I am using SqlAlchemy to connect to a postgres database.  My goal is to write a simple `SELECT *` query using the ORM and convert the result to a pandas dataframe.

Within my class, `self._pg_client` is a Session object, and `Matches` is a table defined in the data model.

```
from base import Matches
from pandas import pd

...

class GetData(object):
    def __init__(self, pg_client: Session):
        self._pg_client: Session = pg_client

    def run(self):

        print(type(self._pg_client))
        query = self._pg_client.query(Matches).all()
        print(query.statement)
```

After instantiating a `GetData()` object and running it, the first print statement returns:

```
<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session'>
```

as is expected.  However the second returns an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'statement'
```

`query` is actually a list object of results from the query, not the query itself.  A few other posts have suggested passing the query statement ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525808/sqlalchemy-orm-conversion-to-pandas-dataframe), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61253952/sqlalchemy-orm-conversion-to-pandas-dataframe-with-bigquery)) to `read_sql()`, but I cannot seem to get the statment itself.  I try the following:

```
matches = pd.read_sql(self._pg_client.query(Matches).all().statement, self._pg_client.bind)
```

which fails because the list object does not have a statement attribute.  What is the correct way to get the query statement from an ORM query in SQLalchemy? Is this all that is needed to pass to `read_sql` ?

Comment: `Query.all()` executes and returns a list, so don't call it, if you want the `Query` object itself.

Comment: As @IljaEverilä pointed out: `query = self._pg_client.query(Matches); print(query)` before you do `results = query.all()`