# fastapi session with sqlalchemy bugging out

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm using fastapi to create a basic API to do some statistics from a postgres database.

I have just started using sqlalchemy as I want to do connection pooling, and based off of my googling it seems the route to go down.

I've implemented this in my main.py file,

```
def get_db():
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

Then using depends from fastapi with my URL params,

```
async def get_data(xxx ,db: SessionLocal = Depends(get_db)):
   conn = db()
```

With the sessions function being,

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from environment.config import settings


SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = settings.DATABASE_URL
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False,autoflush=False,bind=engine)
```

I'm receiving a type error of SessionLocal not being callable, wondering what I'm missing here?

The issue I was having was when testing the API against being called, multiple calls to the API were essentially recreating a connection to the database, which was super laggy just testing locally - so wanting to make that...well work :)

#### Imports for Main.py

```
from plistlib import UID
import string
from typing import Optional

from pandas import concat

from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Header,Depends

from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware


from pydantic import BaseModel

from db.session import SessionLocal

from biometrics.TaskGet import GetSentiment, GetScheduled, GetAllActualSubstance, GetEmotions

import aggregate.biometric_aggregators as biometric_aggregators

import os
```

Based on answer below, I just let it use DB. Now I get this error weirdly though.

```
web_1  | AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

Made sqlalchemy functions to do the same calls, now getting the same error as before.

I originally tried to just return the function without using pd.read_sql, but it didn't work - any idea on what I've done wrong here?

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

import pandas as pd

from . import models


def sentimentDataframe(db: Session, user_id: str):
    Sentiment = pd.read_sql((get_sentiment(db,user_id)),con=db)
    Sentiment['created'] =pd.to_datetime(Sentiment['created'], unit='s')
    return Sentiment.set_index('created')


def get_sentiment(db: Session, user_id: str, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return db.query(models.Sentiment).filter(models.Sentiment.user_id == user_id).order_by(models.Sentiment.created.desc()).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()
```

Comment: can you provide imports of your `main.py`?

Comment: You're sending a db session to a function written to use a dbapi compatible connection. Use `db.bind` to get the underlying bound connection. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525808/sqlalchemy-orm-conversion-to-pandas-dataframe for a full example (using the ORM layer as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be doing this

```
conn = db()
```

as db is already an instance of session

You can already use it like so

```
db.add(<SQLAlchemy Base Instance>)
db.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks - When i do this, I get this error now,

Comment: web_1  | AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Comment: What is cursor? Update your question then)

Comment: Ahhh, I am not sure what a cursor actually is :)

Comment: Provide full code snippet for `get_data` then, please

Comment: have done above, should probably be more mindful with SQL queries but eh

Comment: I think you should either rewrite your raw sql to sqlalchemy pythonic sql query builder (or much better - to orm queries) or use `psycopg2` instead of sqlalchemy's session (I do not suggest using that as it's plain headache to integrate it with sqlalchemy and fastapi)

Comment: Ahhhh, so i can't just use plain old SQL queries? I feel like learning an ORM versus using SQL and building that knowledge is a better bad idea overall

Comment: SQLAlchemy does not only provide ORM for building sql, but transactions, local sessions, connection pools and more. Using raw SQL and default Postgres driver (`psycopg2`) does not give you any of that. And most of the times writing ORM queries is much easier, faster and more robust. SQLAlchemy core provides very easy to understand query builder as it looks as native sql in pythonic syntax

Comment: Made changes to use the ORM based on your advice, still not working :/